# Not showing output on output terminal

Tags: python, output

I have installed extension of python in visual code and also installed code runner extension. When I write python codes and run it it shows that the code is successfully runs but there is no output of those codes on output terminal

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The output (at least for me) isn't used to actually show the file-output. For that I use the terminal. The output just shows me my pylint. Make sure you set your 'Code' to 'Python'. Hope that helps.